# What is the maximum possible temperature a MOSFET can reach?

Tags: mosfet, thermal, powermosfet

I'm choosing a switch for a power supply design. I would like to know the highest temperature the MOSFET can reach. The switch that I'm using is [DMT3020LDV](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMT3020LDV.pdf).

An input having 24 V and 8 A is supplied to the drain of the switch. The following are my calculations for the junction temperature:

\$T_j = T_a + (P_t \times R_{ja})\$

Where:

\$T_j\$ = Junction Temperature;
\$T_a\$ = Ambient Temperature;
\$P_t\$ = Total Power Dissipation = 0.9 W (from datasheet);
\$R_{ja}\$ = Thermal Resistance, junction to ambient = 138 °C/W (from datasheet)

So, \$T_j\$ = 25(room temperature) + (0.9 x 138) = 150°C.

But if the outside temperature is 85°C, will \$T_j\$ = 85 + (0.9 x 138) = 210°C?

Are my calculations correct? Because 210°C is too high in my opinion.

Comment: 210 is correct but too hot,  solder a heatsink to the drain,  see also figure 6

Comment: Thank You @Jasen for the quick response.

Comment: Thank You @JYelton for editing the question.

Comment: Your calculations are correct.  You can look at the thermal section of the datasheet which lists the max operating junction temperature as 150°C.  You'll either need to dramatically reduce your power consumption (which is probably not feasible), or dramatically reduce the thermal resistance.  Rja = 138 is for minimal copper.  Rja = 67 for 1 in sq copper plate.

Comment: @BEE I'm very limited on the space and 1 in sq plates are going to be very tough, but even if I do that, the Rja and Pt product is still around '125' (67 x 1.9). It would have been great if the product was around '75'. What I'm still wondering is, would the MOSFET temperature be related to the input of drain? Meaning whether the input is '12v, 1A' or '24v, 8A', will the MOSFET still reach 210 *C if the outside temperature is 85 *C? Forgive me for newbie questions, I'm still learning.

Comment: As you can see from the equations, the operating Tj is related to the ambient temperature, power dissipation, and the thermal resistance.  You will have to make adjustments to one or more of those to get a different result.

Comment: Work backwards. Tambient_max = Tjmax - Power(Rth_ca + Rth_jc) .| This tells you how hot the ambient can be for a given desired Power level, give Rthjc (fixed by manufacturer) and Rthca - set by heatsinking. eg at 10 Watts, Tjmax = 150c, Rjc = 3 C/W, Rthca = 10 C/W-> Tambient max = 150 - 10W x (3 + 10) = 150 - 130 = 20c ! :-(. | Change to a 2C?W heatsing and you get Tambmax = 150 - 10 x (3+2) = 150-50 = 100C. Adjust assumptions to suit.

Comment: If you intend to operate above 100'C they better be void of moisture. otherwise popcorn effects.  125'C is generally safe and 85'C for reliability. look up Arrhenius effects. Unless specially design for down the well high temps, dont be a heat miser...

Comment: Can reach, should reach or be designed  for long life...? rephrase your question. also lack of air flow and enclosure can degrade these specs significantly

Comment: WARNING: You need to understand power dissipation. If you have a low Rdson MOSFET and it is usually hard on or off then dissipation at 8A is "lowish". eg I^2R at say 30 milliOhm = 64 x 0.030 ~= 2 Watts. Add to that some switching loses and it is still liable to work well with sensible minimal heatsinking. If the FET operates partially NOT in on/off mode then it will be different or much different. Show us your circuit

Comment: show more calculation detai;. What is the duty cycle? Where did the 0.9W dissipation come from? - 40% on time?

Comment: choose a mosfet with a lower on resistance (so there's less heat), or use several mosfets in parallel reducinfg the resistance and spreading the heat

Comment: *The switch that I'm using is DMT3020LDV* - switches don't dissipate (in normal operation very much) and switches are not MOSFETs.

Comment: You calculated the power dissipation using the typical Rdson of 14mΩ. Better is to use the worst case Rdson of 20mΩ, for 0.02·8² ≈ 1.3W. Because that's how much one fo those mosfets may dissipate.

Answer (score 1):

Work backwards.
For  desired power level and known other parameters you can calculate maximuj allowed ambient.
Rearrange as desired.

1 ... Tambient_max = Tjmax - Power(Rth_ca + Rth_jc)
or
2 ... Power_max = (Tamb-Tjmax) / (Rth_ca + Rth_jc)
or
3 ... Rthca = (Tjmax - Tambmax)/ Power - Rthjc

So (1) - Tambient_max = Tjmax - Power(Rth_ca + Rth_jc) tells you how hot the ambient can be for a given desired Power level, given Rthjc (fixed by manufacturer) and Rthca - set by heatsinking.

eg at P = 10 Watts, Tjmax = 150 c, Rjc = 3 c/W, Rthca = 10 c/W
(1) gives ...  Tambient max = 150 - 10W x (3 + 10) = 150 - 130
= 20c :-(.

Change to a 2c / W heatsink and you get
Tambmax = 150 - 10 x (3+2) = 150-50 
= 100 c.

ie IF you can get the case within 2c of the water then you can cool it with boiling water :-)

Adjust assumptions to suit.

---

You need to understand power dissipation.
If you have a low Rdson MOSFET and it is usually hard on or off then dissipation at 8A is "lowish". eg I^2R at say 30 milliOhm = 64 x 0.030 ~= 2 Watts.
Add to that some switching loses and it is still liable to work well with sensible minimal heatsinking.

If the FET operates partially NOT in on/off mode then it will be different or much different.

Show us your circuit

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the MOSFET. The key parameter is the junction temperature. Current parts with a 175 C rating are available. There are silicon carbide "MOSFETs" that have a much higher rating. I used them as custom parts, I do not know if they are available on the open market. They were not inexpensive.

Using the calculations given earlier you can work backwards to determine how much heat you can dissipate. From that you can calculate your max current.

Comment: Looks like there are a few around, but the junction temp doesnt seem to be super high (https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/genesic-semiconductor/G3R350MT12J/13280409)